# Bind from searchBar to TableView in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have `UISearchBar and SearchDisplayController` in the `Main.storyboard` embedded in a `UIViewController`s' `UIView`. Below I have `UITableView`. I am trying to use `RxSwift` to pipe the user input from `UISearchBar` straight into `UITableView`, doing results' filtering in-between. Pretty much it is autocomplete functionality that I am trying to implement. Somehow I am getting an error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Failure converting from Optional() to UISearchBarDelegate

Here is the code that I have:

```
private func setUpAutocomplete() {
    // Define intput stream
    searchBar.rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .map({
            (query: String) -> [String] in
            let res = AllGenes.filter { $0.hasPrefix(query) }
            return res
        })
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier,
                                     cellType: GeneSeachTableViewCell.self)) {  row, gene, cell in
                                        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(gene) \(row)"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to directly pipe the input, but did it in two steps:

```
     searchBar.rx.text
        .orEmpty
        .subscribe(onNext: {query in
            self.shownGenes.value = AllGenes.filter { $0.hasPrefix(query) }
        })

        self.shownGenes
            .asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellIdentifier,
                                     cellType: GeneSeachTableViewCell.self)) {  row, gene, cell in
                                        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(gene) \(row)"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Where `shownGenes = Variable<[String]>([])`. And I also removed `UISearchBar and SearchDisplayController` and substituted it for just `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when the `UISearchBar` delegate had been set to my view controller in the storyboard.  Try opening up the storyboard in interface builder and right-clicking on the search bar.  If you see a connection for the delegate then remove it.  Hope that helps